# golang bun orm embed struct but keep ID as first column

Tags: go, orm

I am using uptrace/bun as ORM for golang. I want to create a table for an existing struct Order by adding primary key `ID` and `created` columns. I am embedding struct as follows but want to keep `ID` as the first column in db. How can it be done?

```
type MyOrder struct {
    *Order
    ID        int64     `bun:",pk,autoincrement"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `bun:",nullzero,default:now()"`
}
```

This creates the table but id is second last column while listing records in db.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply to place ID first in the order of fields in the MyOrder struct